# how to download/copy the audio transcript from flash player(swf)

Tags: javascript, flash, caching, browser, google-chrome-extension

I have opened a presentation(flash swf) in browser which is located in server.
I am able to see the audio transcript for the presentation by clicking audio transcript button but am unable to copy/download it to save it in my local.

I would like to know how to download/copy the audio transcript. something  like from browser cache or using any tool or browser extension.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/hURElq6VPcc).

> (1) just goto the page with flash file(swf file) you want to save
>   (2) press ctrl+U to enter view source of the page(it will be opened in a separate tab)
>   (3) press ctrl+F to open the find box on top right corner of the "view source" page and type "swf" (withought quotes)
>   (4) now right-click on links ending with ".swf" (ie- http://brainteasers.ic.cz/zip/frogsgame.swf ) and click save as AND SAVE IT

You may also check this [video tutorial](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjb182Pn5bYAhVBG5QKHX7pAEsQtwIIOjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DHGtpubyTx94&usg=AOvVaw31vacykkzsOQfbDwl4ZtXI) on how to extract audio from an SWF File.